# SQL: Import and Export Data Wizard 64bit not showing Excel workbook option

Tags: sql, excel, database, import, 64-bit

I'm using a 64bit computer and I'm trying to upload an excel file to the database with the "Import and Export Data Wizard" 64bit but no Excel workbook option. Someone can help me please?

[image]